# Why this boolean doesn't give me the right value?

Tags: c, boolean, principles

First of all, my program functions, but the `b3` expression (a `boolean`) does not function like I want to. Instead of giving me a value of 0 (false) when I select that one train is DIESEL or ELECTRICAL, it gives me a value of 1 (TRUE) when some of the trains are DIESEL or ELECTRICAL. It only gives false when both trains are ELECTRICAL or both DIESEL. When one train is ELECTRICAL and the other DIESEL, it keeps me giving me 1 (TRUE). My code is more extensive but these are the parts related to the problem that I account for.

```
typedef enum{ELECTRICAL, CARBON, SOLAR, GASOLINE, DIESEL, MAGNETIC} tPropulsion;    
typedef enum{FALSE, TRUE} boolean;    
int main()
{
    tPropulsion propulsionType1, propulsionType2;
    boolean b2, b3, b4;

    printf("Insert type of propulsion of train1>> 0-ELECTRICAL, 1-CARBON, 2-SOLAR, 3 GASOLINE, 4-DIESEL, 5-MAGNETIC ");
    scanf("%u", &propulsionType1);

    printf("Insert type of propulsion of train2>> 0-ELECTRICAL, 1-CARBON, 2-SOLAR, 3 GASOLINE, 4-DIESEL, 5-MAGNETIC ");
    scanf("%u", &propulsionType2);

    b3 = propulsionType1 != DIESEL && propulsionType2 != ELECTRICAL && 
    propulsionType1 != DIESEL && propulsionType2 != ELECTRICAL;


    printf("Neither train 1 or train 2 are DIESEL or ELECTRICAL is (0-FLASE, 1-TRUE)>> %u", b3);
}
```

Comment: Please show your input and output. BTW, why do you have your comparisons twice in the expression?

Comment: You realize that you are repeating the same conditions 2 times in a row? Should get a warning from the compiler.

Comment: You need `b3 = propulsionType1 != DIESEL && propulsionType1 != ELECTRICAL && propulsionType2 != DIESEL && propulsionType2 != ELECTRICAL;`. The order of the terms doesn't matter, but you need all four conditions, not the same two conditions repeated twice as in your original code.

Comment: Can you explain why my order does not function? With your answer now it functions, thanks!. As well i'm sorry if I'm asking for too much explanations, but i'm spaniard and English is not my mother language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- indent your code
- use parenthesis
- rather than using enum for boolean, you could do your own boolean like this:

```
#define TRUE (0==0)
#define FALSE !TRUE
```

Then clarify your statement, what do you want?

"if train 1 or train 2 is DIESEL or ELECTRICAL then TRUE, else FALSE"

```
    b3 = ((propulsionType1 == DIESEL) || (propulsionType2 == ELECTRICAL)) ||
    ((propulsionType1 == DIESEL) || (propulsionType2 == ELECTRICAL));
```

Then look at propulsionType1 and propulsionType2

```
    b3 = ((propulsionType1 == DIESEL) || (propulsionType1 == ELECTRICAL)) ||
    ((propulsionType2 == DIESEL) || (propulsionType2 == ELECTRICAL));
```

Comment: I think your `b3` value is the inverse of what is required. `b3` should be false if either train has a propulsion type of diesel or electrical, otherwise true.

Comment: I know, what i wanted to say is, to clarify a statement, i'd rather put in "positive", then do a ```!answer```. Because i wasn't sure that its statement was the expected one.

Comment: I have a few of questions. If you use #define TRUE (0==0)
#define FALSE !TRUE you are not saying that FALSE is 1 and TRUE is 0? Using my enum for the boolean allowed me to put FALSE as 0 and TRUE as 1. I ask because I don't know. As well, I tried to use this || and it doesn't work even though I changed the order of the terms as Ian abbot told me. I didn't try to put the  #define, because the thing that I say. TRUE will be 0 and FALSE 1. Or I am wrong? (I'm spaniard and beginner so sorry)